# VB.NET :Error on combobox's SelectedValueChanged event on form's load

Tags: vb.net, form-load

I've a function `fill_cboarea`(to fill a *combobox* called `cboarea`).This function will *call* on `Form_load`.While reaching this `fill_cboarea` *func* debugger goes to  `cboarea_SelectedValueChanged` because i have written some piece of code in it.Below given is the error.

> Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'DataRowView' and type 'Integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a checking in `cboarea_SelectedValueChanged`

i.e

```
Private Sub cboarea_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
                             System.EventArgs) Handles cboarea.SelectedValueChanged

    Dim item As DataRowView = TryCast(Me.cboarea.SelectedItem, DataRowView)    
    If item.IsEdit = False Then'check whether the cboarea is in edit mode (on load)
       'here your some piece of code
    End If
End Sub
```